# Kohana 3.2 Validation in Birthdate

Tags: php, kohana

what i wanted to do is to validate if the age is not under 18 or over 33

```
public function validate($arr) {
    return Validation::factory($arr)
        ->rule('username', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('last_name', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('first_name', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('email', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('email', 'email_domain')
        ->rule('phone_num', 'not_empty')
        ->rule('birthdate', 'not_empty')
        ->rule( 'birthdate', array( $this, 'check_birthday' ) );     
}

public function check_birthday()
{
    check if age is not under 18 or over 33
   return boolean;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Kohana_Date constants, something like:

`return ($date < (time() - 18 * Date::YEAR)) AND ($date > (time() - 33 * Date::YEAR));`

or

`return Valid::range($date, time() - 33 * Date::YEAR, time() - 18 * Date::YEAR);`

Turn the date format into timestamp with `strtotime` if you need.

Comment: well it worked btw how to add an error message on this if its below 18 or over 33?

Comment: @MarkFs messages are defined in the messages folder, using the method name in this case